# Calculate field based on a set value if optional parameter is not specified

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, parameters

In my model, I have a `Calculate Field` which will populate the field with a certain integer (in this case, 0). I've added an optional integer model parameter `Start ID`, where the user can specify the integer if they want.

[image: Model]

If `Start ID` is given a value by the user, this value must be used as the expression for `Calculate Field`, else `Expression` must be used. Since the tool can only take one expression as an input, would I have to create a copy of the `Calculate Field` with `Start ID` as the expression, and use `Merge Branch` with an `if` statement to test which branch must run i.e. the `Start ID` branch only runs if it has a value, else run the `Expression` branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can be done much more simply using a model like this:

[image]

where the If/Then logic is part of the Calculate Field tool:

[image]

Think of the `newValue = 123 + 456` part being your Expression.

In my test this will calculate a field to be 479 (`= 123 + 456`) if nothing is entered by the user for Start ID (which is an Optional parameter) or whatever integer value they enter otherwise.